# import geometry from houdini with vertex groups and vertex color

Tags: import

I'm just trying to find a good workflow which will enable me to import both vertex colour and vertex or prim groups from Houdini, and then have them as editable vertex groups/colours in blender.

I've tried obj, fbx, and alembic so far.  With Obj I can get the vertex groups in if i choose 'keep vert order' and tick 'poly groups', but then I don't get the vertex colours.

With fbx I can get the vertex colour only, no groups.

alembic brings through vertex colour only too.

Any way to get both vertex colour and vertex groups, also I notice that only groups created as primitive groups in houdini can be imported as vertex groups in blender, so if there's a single vertex, then that won't get imported, any way around that?

Comment: i am trying to do reverse ( blender vertex groups to houdini groups and totally failing :) please do let me know if you have some idea. thanks